# How to export Excel to JSON in specific format

Tags: json, excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using the following codes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()   

Dim excelRange As Range

Dim jsonItems As New Collection

Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary

Dim jsonFileObject As New FileSystemObject

Dim jsonFileExport As TextStream

Dim i As Long

Dim cell As Variant


Set excelRange = Sheet1.Cells(3, 3).CurrentRegion

For i = 4 To excelRange.Rows.Count

    jsonDictionary("ID") = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)

    jsonDictionary("Pass") = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)

    jsonDictionary("MN") = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)

    jsonDictionary("Email") = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)

    jsonItems.Add jsonDictionary

    Set jsonDictionary = Nothing

Next i

MsgBox (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=0))

Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile(Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.json), *.json"), True)

jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3))
```

I got JSON file in following format:

```
[
   {
      "id": "AA2478FV",

      "PAss": "MAAS",

      "MN": "9878965421",

      "email": "",Abc@123
}]
```

But I need JSON in the following format:

```
{"b2b deatils":[{"id":"01AF2578T","pass":"N","MN":8789755654,"furdetails":[{"nameorg":

[{"emp":1,"itm_det":{"recmount":0}}]}]
```

How can I get this ?

Comment: what happened to email? Also, how are you distinguishing what needs to go where? At present everything gets added to a dict. We don't know the layout of your data either so you will need a table that determines which items go into which dictionary and which dictionary goes where in structure and we would need to know this for all possible key,values.

Comment: Sir I want to convert excel to JSON in following format:

Comment: {"b2b deatils":[{"id":"01AF2578T","pass":"N","MN":8789755654,"furdetails":[{"nameorg":

[{"emp":1,"itm_det":{"recmount":0}}]}]